# Simulating ' ' (single quotations) across a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to pass a date into a function `func`.

The parameter is in the form of `dd-mm-yyyy` and works when I use `'15-05-2019'` as a parameter.

How would code have to be written to accept dates from a Pandas column?

In my case I have all my dates stored in a `dates` column, and I'd like to have a way that I can loop with, instead of applying single ticks to all the dates individually.

For some background to my problem:

`df['day'] = df.apply(lambda row: func('15-05-2019'), axis=1)`
works, giving me a pandas column that displays the day of the date.

How can I automate this for all rows using my `dates` column?

Sample Data:

[image: Table displaying dummy data with columns for 'dates' and 'day']

Here is the function `func`:

```py
def func(date):
    date = str(date)
    d = date[0:2]
    m = date[3:5]
    y = date[6:]
    day = dayofweek(int(d), int(m), int(y))
    return day
```

Although, this may not be needed, this is the auxiliary function.

```py
def dayofweek(d, m, y): 
    t = [ 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 ] 
    y -= m < 3
    day = (( y + int(y / 4) - int(y / 100) + int(y / 400) + t[m - 1] + d) % 7)
    if day == 1:
        return "Monday"
    if day == 2:
        return "Tuesday"
    if day == 3:
        return "Wednesday"
    if day == 4:
        return "Thursday"
    if day == 5:
        return "Friday"
    if day == 6:
        return "Saturday"
    if day == 7:
        return "Sunday"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['day'] = df['dates'].apply(func)
```

EDIT: You can convert values to datetimes and then call [`Series.dt.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html), also if possible some non datetimes is necessaray add parameter `errors=coerce` for convert them to `NaT`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10).tolist() + [10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': rng})  

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce')
df['day'] = df['dates'].dt.day_name()
print (df)
        dates        day
0  2017-04-03     Monday
1  2017-04-04    Tuesday
2  2017-04-05  Wednesday
3  2017-04-06   Thursday
4  2017-04-07     Friday
5  2017-04-08   Saturday
6  2017-04-09     Sunday
7  2017-04-10     Monday
8  2017-04-11    Tuesday
9  2017-04-12  Wednesday
10        NaT        NaN
```

Comment: I received a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`, for both the snippets.

Comment: @VHejeebu - hmmm, can you add some sample data with your function to question?

Comment: Updated the question with a sample. Would you like any other information?

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases, `map` will work as well:

```
df['day'] = df['dates'].map(lambda x: func(list(map(int,x.split('-')))[0], list(map(int,x.split('-')))[1], list(map(int,x.split('-')))[2]))
```

Comment: I received a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10, for both the snippets

Comment: @VHejeebu That means it's a problem in the function, please show it to us.

Comment: Updated the question to have functions

Comment: Received an error, `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`. It seems to work otherwise.

Comment: @VHejeebu Try it now